# Loop value in SQL column

Tags: sql, t-sql, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.Net page that has SQL for its back end. I need to be able to present the user with an auto-generated value say 200 and then auto-increment this value by 1 but then after it gets to a certain value say 300, I need to loop the value back to 200. What is the best way to go about this? I was thinking of using a stored procedure that looks at the current value and then depending on what it is either updates or loops around. Is that the best way to go about this? If so, then how do you link in a stored procedure with an ASP.Net MVC4 web page?

Comment: If you just want an integer, where does a SQL database come into it?

Comment: The value needs to be stored in the database. They want to keep track of these values. --IE #202 was used on x date and x date.

Comment: But why do you need the value generated in the database? Generate it in your .NET code then save it to the database.

Answer (score 0):

Here is some example code to get you started

```sql
-- prevent "row(s) affected" messages in message pane
set nocount on

create table dbo.LoopGenerator (
    id bigint identity(0,1),
    date_generated datetime default getdate()
)

-- example use within a loop demonstrating the looping behavior requested

declare @i int = 0, @value int

while @i < 101
begin
    insert dbo.LoopGenerator default values
    -- scope_identity(): the generated id
    -- 100: the difference between the min value and max value
    -- 200: the min value
    set @value = scope_identity() % 100 + 200
    -- print the looping value; you can see this in your Messages pane after running it
    print @value
    set @i += 1
end

-- Show the resulting data stored in the table
select *
from dbo.LoopGenerator

drop table dbo.LoopGenerator
```